# deleting a question I have posted to stackexchange site

Tags: support, delete

I posted a question that I had no useful reply, just comments which did not answer it. How can I delete this question?

Comment: be patient, maybe answer will appear after week, month ... probably to late for you but useful for someone else, who will have in future similar problem ... if question is related to `skak` package (i guess), i can't help you , but we newer know if in (near) future one will be able to do.

Comment: I posted the same problem in my first question in a different manner, and I got good comments or answers; so I want to delete the first question which I think was not properly asked.

Comment: then is better to reword it. delete own question is rather simple. below it you can see four keys: `share`, `edit`, `reopen`, `delete` and `flag`. just click on `delete` and that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the question there is an option to `delete` the post:

[image]

Note that deletion may not be possible as there are certain criteria that has to be met. Read [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244) for more information.